# How can I loop over a function with multiple inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, finance

I am trying to collect returns for my research from a function (code below). Unfortunately I can only get it to loop over all the dates but not through all the index values. What I have tried:

```
for i in index_c.iloc[:,1:]:
    for dt in MICH_CONSUMER_SENTIMENT['Date']:
        c=get_cum_returns(index_c,i,dt,6,5,'MXUS Index')
        cum_ret['index_return'].append(c[0])
        cum_ret['bench_return'].append(c[1])
        cum_ret['abnormal_return'].append(c[2])
        cum_ret['date'].append(dt)
```

I can get one for loop working: *for dt in MICH_CONSUMER_SENTIMENT['Date']:...*, so that it appends all the date values for one index in the dictionary 'cum_ret'. But if I try to loop dates and index names I get the following error and it only appends part of the data in the dict:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcDW3.png)

How could I solve this problem, so that all the values would be appended in the dictionary? Is there an alternative way to approach this problem? I am sure there is, it is just that I am fairly new to Python.

**FUNCTION**

```
def get_cum_returns(prices, sid, date, days_before, days_after, 
    benchmark_sid):
    """
    Calculates cumulative and abnormal returns for the sid & benchmark
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    prices : pd.DataFrame
        Pricing history DataFrame obtained from `get_pricing`. Index should
        be the datetime index and sids should be columns.
    sid : int or zipline.assets._assets.Equity object
        Security that returns are being calculated for.
    date : datetime object
        Date that will be used as t=0 for cumulative return calcuations. All
        returns will be calculated around this date.
    days_before, days_after : int
        Days before/after to be used to calculate returns for.
    benchmark :  int or zipline.assets._assets.Equity object
    
    Returns
    -------
    sid_returns : pd.Series
        Cumulative returns time series from days_before ~ days_after from date
        for sid
    benchmark_returns : pd.Series
        Cumulative returns time series for benchmark sid
    abnormal_returns : pd.Series
        Abnormal cumulative returns time series for sid compared against 
    benchmark
    """
    prices=index_c
    date=dt
    days_before, days_after=6,5
    sid=i
    benchmark_sid='MXUS Index'
    day_zero_index = prices.index.searchsorted(date)
    #print 'day_zero_index', day_zero_index
    starting_index = max(day_zero_index - days_before, 0)
    ending_index   = min(day_zero_index + days_after + 1, len(prices.index) - 1)

    if starting_index < 0 or ending_index >= len(prices.index):
        assert False #is this possible
        return None
    
    if sid == benchmark_sid:
        temp_price = prices.iloc[starting_index:ending_index,:].loc[:,[sid]]
    else:
        temp_price = prices.iloc[starting_index:ending_index,:].loc[:,[sid, 
    benchmark_sid]]
            
    beta = calc_beta(sid, benchmark_sid, temp_price)
    if beta is None:
        #print 'beta is None'
        return
    
    daily_ret = temp_price.pct_change().fillna(0)
    
    daily_ret['abnormal_returns'] = daily_ret[sid] - 
    beta*daily_ret[benchmark_sid]
    
    cum_returns = (daily_ret + 1).cumprod() - 1
    
    try:
        # If there's not enough data for event study,
        # return None
        cum_returns.index = range(starting_index - day_zero_index,
                                  ending_index - day_zero_index)
    except e:
        print ('exception', e)
        return None
    
    sid_returns      = cum_returns[sid] - cum_returns[sid].iloc[0]
    bench_returns    = cum_returns[benchmark_sid] - 
    cum_returns[benchmark_sid].iloc[0]
    abnormal_returns = cum_returns['abnormal_returns'] - 
    cum_returns['abnormal_returns'].iloc[0]
    
    return sid_returns, bench_returns, abnormal_returns
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Regards, Jaka

Comment: where is `cum_ret` defined?

Comment: As a dictionary: `cum_ret={'date':[],'index_return':[],'bench_return':[],'abnormal_return':[]}`

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the problem:

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Your function can occasionally return `None`, ie.: if an exception is caught. But your loop then doesn't check if `c` is `None`, and attempts to subscript it, ie.: pretend it's a list.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Some time series have missing values. So I have to include and `if` `else` statement to check and skip missing values?

Comment: Exactly - the `get_cum_returns` function handles errors by returning `None`, but the for loop does not. I would simply add a line `if c:` after the `c=get_cum_returns` line. If the function returns something, it gets processed. If not, it goes to the next loop.